# expand dates in two columns based on another two columns with ranges

Tags: mysql, r, date, dplyr, data.table

I have table 1 as given in the Rcode below.  This table gives the start and end ranges of dates.

I have another table,table 2 which gives the outer ends of ranges of dates that should contain start and end ranges from table 1.

My final table should look like given in Rcode below.

Final table should have the exact ranges as in table 1 and table 2 ranges should be adjusted so that the end dates are continuous to succeeding  and preceding rows. In other words, final table should have non-overlapping intervals.  A complex date problem that I have been unsuccessfully trying to solve.  Hope I have explained it clearly.

The following code will give table 1 and table2.

```
table1 <- read.table(text="
id  start         end      var1
A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992  1
A   03/24/1992  03/26/1992  2
A   03/28/1992  03/31/1992  5
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  1
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

start   <- as.Date(start)
end     <- as.Date(end)
table1      <- data.frame(id,start, end, var1) 
setDT(table1)


table2 <- read.table(text="
id  t1            t2       var2
A   01/01/1992  03/16/1992  3
A   03/17/1992  03/19/1992  4
A   03/20/1992  05/25/1992  6
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  8
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

t1   <- as.Date(t1)
t2     <- as.Date(t2)
table2     <- data.frame(id,t1, t2, var2)
setDT(table2)



finaltable <- read.table(text="
id  t1             t2     var1  var2
A   01/01/1992  03/14/1992      3
A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992  1   
A   03/21/1992  03/23/1992      6
A   03/24/1992  03/26/1992  2   
A   03/27/1992  03/27/1992      6
A   03/28/1992  03/31/1992  5   
A   04/01/1992  05/25/1992      6
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  1   8
  ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Do you want a dyplr solution only, or would a SQL solution be fine?

Comment: Thanks GMB.  Either are fine.

Comment: would you like to explain the logic to create var1 and var2 when there are overlapping intervals?

Comment: Thanks chinsoon12.  Final table should have the exact ranges from table1 along with the var1.  Table2 ranges will not be exact as they will be adjusted so that we have continuous, non-overlapping intervals with the corresponding var2 values.

Comment: hi why is the var2 for B equals to 8 but the var2 for A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992 not equal to 4?

Comment: For the final table,var2 for A 03/15/1992 03/20/1992 comes from table1 and with that comes its associated value of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
#get first and last rows by id for each table
d1 <- table1[, .SD[c(1L, .N)], id][, ri := rowid(id)][]
d2 <- table2[, .SD[c(1L, .N)], id][, ri := rowid(id)][]

#create the earliest and latest intervals to row bind to original table1
morerows <- d1[d2, on=.(id, ri)][, 
    .(id, start=fifelse(ri==1L, t1, end+1L), end=fifelse(ri==1L, start-1L, t2))][
        start<=end]
DT1 <- rbindlist(list(table1, morerows), use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
setkey(DT1, id, start, end)

#add in missing intervals
ans <- rbindlist(list(DT1, DT1[, .(start=end[-.N]+1L, end=start[-1L]-1L), id]), 
    use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)[start<=end]
setkey(ans, id, start, end)

ans[is.na(var1), var2 := table2[.SD, on=.(id, t1<=start, t2>=start), var2]]
ans[is.na(var2), var2 := table2[.SD, on=.(id, t1=start, t2=start), var2]]
```

output:

```
   id      start        end var1 var2
1:  A 1992-01-01 1992-03-14   NA    3
2:  A 1992-03-15 1992-03-20    1   NA
3:  A 1992-03-21 1992-03-23   NA    6
4:  A 1992-03-24 1992-03-26    2   NA
5:  A 1992-03-27 1992-03-27   NA    6
6:  A 1992-03-28 1992-03-31    5   NA
7:  A 1992-04-01 1992-05-25   NA    6
8:  B 1994-06-06 1994-06-06    1    8
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
table1 <- fread("id  start         end      var1
A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992  1
A   03/24/1992  03/26/1992  2
A   03/28/1992  03/31/1992  5
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  1")
cols <- c("start", "end")
table1[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), .SDcols=cols]

table2 <- fread("id  t1            t2       var2
A   01/01/1992  03/16/1992  3
A   03/17/1992  03/19/1992  4
A   03/20/1992  05/25/1992  6
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  8")
cols <- c("t1", "t2")
table2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), .SDcols=cols]

finaltable <- fread("id  t1             t2     var1  var2
A   01/01/1992  03/14/1992  NA    3
A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992  1   NA
A   03/21/1992  03/23/1992  NA    6
A   03/24/1992  03/26/1992  2   NA
A   03/27/1992  03/27/1992  NA    6
A   03/28/1992  03/31/1992  5   NA
A   04/01/1992  05/25/1992  NA    6
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  1   8")
cols <- c("t1", "t2")
finaltable[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), .SDcols=cols]
```

Comment: Thank you!  Thank you! Thank you!  Much, much appreciated Chinsoon12.  I had just not been able to do this.  The var=8 for id=B comes from table2 as those exact ranges exist is both table1 and table 2.

Comment: I just realized that for some IDs, the number of rows are not the same in both tables and the above code skips the end points. For example if table 2 is 
table2 <- fread("id  t1            t2       var2
A   02/02/1992  03/16/1992  3
A   03/17/1992  03/19/1992  4
A   03/20/1992  05/25/1992  6
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  8")
cols <- c("t1", "t2")
table2[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), .SDcols=cols]

Comment: @Pam, I am assuming that *I have another table,table 2 which gives the outer ends of ranges of dates that should contain start and end ranges from table 1.* that is table 2 need to cover the range in table 1

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  Again, thanks so much for the code!

Comment: The code skips the last date in table2 , if table 1 has only one row, code given below.  The final table must contain all the dates and IDs from table2 and table 1.   table1 <- fread("id  start         end      var1
A   03/18/1992  03/24/1992  5")
cols <- c("start", "end")
table1[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), .SDcols=cols]

Comment: Thanks a million Chinsoon!!!!  This was very very helpful!

Comment: @Pam no problem. thanks for the interesting question. good brain exercise as it turned out to be harder than I thought.

Comment: Hi Chinsoon, I have posted another question similar to this one, but with some differences.  I was given new data and  the start and end dates could lie outside of the ranges in table2.  Would you have the time to help me please?

Comment: Hi Pam, I am sorry as I am quite tied up with work. Hopefully you have received some help from other SO users

Comment: No problem chinsoon. Noone has responded with a solution but I have written a code  Yet to test the code.  Hopefully it works.  I am working from your above code and making some changes to it.  Your code has been extremely helpful!  I can never thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, using the packages `dplyr` and `anytime`:

```r
library(dplyr)

table1 <- read.table(text="
id  start         end      var1
A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992  1
A   03/24/1992  03/26/1992  2
A   03/28/1992  03/31/1992  5
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  1
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F) %>%
  data.frame()

library(anytime)

table1$t1 <- anydate(table1$start)
table1$t2 <- anydate(table1$end)

table2 <- read.table(text="
id  t1            t2       var2
A   01/01/1992  03/16/1992  3
A   03/17/1992  03/19/1992  4
A   03/20/1992  05/25/1992  6
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  8
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F) %>%
  data.frame()

table2$t1 <- anydate(table2$t1)
table2$t2 <- anydate(table2$t2)

finaltable <- merge(table1, table2, by = c("id", "t1", "t2"), all = T) %>%
  select(-c(start, end))
finaltable
#>   id         t1         t2 var1 var2
#> 1  A 1992-01-01 1992-03-16   NA    3
#> 2  A 1992-03-15 1992-03-20    1   NA
#> 3  A 1992-03-17 1992-03-19   NA    4
#> 4  A 1992-03-20 1992-05-25   NA    6
#> 5  A 1992-03-24 1992-03-26    2   NA
#> 6  A 1992-03-28 1992-03-31    5   NA
#> 7  B 1994-06-06 1994-06-06    1    8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks bttomio.  The final table should have non-overlapping intervals.  For eg. for row 1, t2 should be 1992-03-14, row 3-t1 should be 1992-03-21 and so on.